# UICollectionView calling scrollViewDidScroll: when popped from the navigation stack

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, crash, uicollectionview

I have a navigation controller, its root view controller is of type `CollectionViewControllerA`. Upon selecting an item, I have a fade out and expanding animation followed by a call to push a second view controller of type `CollectionVewControllerB` onto the stack:

```
CollectionViewControllerB *b = ... // construction of the view controller to be pushed
[UIView animateWithDuration:.3
                 animations:^{
                     self.collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5);
                     self.collectionView.alpha = 0;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL s){
                     [self.navigationController pushViewController:b animated:NO];
                 }];
```

I pop the view controller in a similar way

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.3
                 animations:^{
                     self.collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.3, .3);
                     self.collectionView.alpha = 0;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL s){
                     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                 }];
```

The problem here is that the app crashes when popping the view controller. Reason:

```
*** -[CollectionViewControllerB scrollViewDidScroll:]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

I understand that the problem is because the popped view controller is destroyed, but why does `scrollViewDidScroll:` get called in the first place? Nothing changes the `contentOffset` of the `collectionView` in code, and there is no user interaction either. Unless changing the `transform` property also triggers the method to get called?

`CollectionViewControllerB` implements `scrollViewDidScroll:` because I need to disable vertical scrolling.

Meanwhile I have a very very messy hack to prevent the crash, that is before the animation, I add

```
self.collectionView.delegate = nil;
```

This stops the method from getting called. But there has to be a better way.

Can anyone shed some light on why `scrollViewDidScroll:` is called and how it can be stopped?

Comment: I have just run into the same issue, but using segues. My solution was the same as yours; on viewWillDisappear nil out the delegate. No idea why this happens. It must be the case that somehow popping changes the contentOffset, but I'm not sure how or why.

Comment: I suppose nil-ing out the delegate is as good a solution as any... seeing that the object is going to be destroyed anyway.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It seems like the only way to solve the problem is what I have already done... setting the delegate to nil before the animation.

```
self.collectionView.delegate = nil;
```

Hopefully this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: I added it in -(void)dealloc method.

Comment: @md_develop that's the best place to put it

Comment: I just had this happen to me with a UITableView. I have no idea why, but setting the delegate to nil fixed it.  However, for some reason, it feels like a hack.

Comment: @Johnny I would say it is a hack. I see no reason for the behaviour and until Apple fixes it (which I think will never happen), this seems to be the best option.

Comment: It seems like fixed the problem I was having (in this case I was using UIScrollView and set self.scrollView.delegate = nil) even though I used ARC. Do all delegates have to be set to nil in dealloc or is it just the bug in this case?

Comment: @SodbilegGansukh all evidences point to this being a bug because I've never had to set delegates to nil for anything else. I don't know if it's been fixed, judging from continued interest it's probably not...

Answer (score 9):

Set `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` inside your view controller.

I had a problem similar to this, and found that on navigating away from the page, the `contentOffset` was changing by 20 every time.

I found that setting this property inside my view controller stopped this changing, and therefor `scrollViewDidScroll` was no longer being called. Turns out the view controller automatically adjusts content insets for changes in status bar, nav bar etc.. even when you navigate away.

I think this is a better solution and proper explanation as to why the scrolling method was being called.

Comment: For me, `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` caused the crash. Setting it back to `YES`, solved the problem. This is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your controller .

```
[self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];
```

Hope this would help you.